# How to reformat JSON in Notepad++?

Tags: json, parsing, notepad++

I need Notepad++ to take a json string from this

```
{"menu": {"id": "file","value": "File","popup": {"menuitem": [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}]}}}
```

to this...

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I looked around at all the TextFX options but couldn't find anything that worked.

Comment: For 32-bit version, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762242.

Answer (score 1743, accepted):

> #### Update:
>
> As of Notepad++ v7.6, use **Plugin Admin** to install JSTool per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56072664/1315626)

INSTALL

Download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/ and copy JSMinNpp.dll to plugin directory of Notepad++. Or you can just install "JSTool" from Plugin Manager in Notepad++.

New Notepad++ install and where did PluginManager go? See [How to view Plugin Manager in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad)

```
{
  "menu" : {
    "id" : "file",
    "value" : "File",
    "popup" : {
      "menuitem" : [{
      "value" : "New",
          "onclick" : "CreateNewDoc()"
        }, {
          "value" : "Open",
          "onclick" : "OpenDoc()"
        }, {
          "value" : "Close",
          "onclick" : "CloseDoc()"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
Tip: Select the code you want to reformat, then Plugins | JSTool | JSFormat.

Comment: Seems to be listed as JSTool now

Comment: Thanks. I checked. I ended up using JSONViewer as it is lets format the JSON data and not just view it in nested tree format.

Comment: JSTool can also format the JSON data. Just press Ctrl-Alt-M. I tried a few plugins now and I find this is the best one.

Comment: did anybody noticed the color after beautify ?

Comment: Ascii plugin: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/files/Asc/JSToolNPP.1.16.10.asc.zip/download

Comment: This can be installed directly from the built in "Plugin Manager" in Notepad++.

Go "Plugins > Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > Available tab"

Comment: Default settings seem to configure the hot key **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **M** for JSFor**m**at and **Ctrl** + **Alt** + **J** for **J**son Viewer

Comment: @prograde I did added the same way,the answer did help as I was earlier searching for just json under languages + plugins.

Comment: A 64-bit version can be downloaded directly from here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/13064/plugin-update-jsonviewer-1-24

Comment: `CTRL + ALT + M` FTW

Comment: Opening the plugin manager I found JSON Viewer right on the list. Worked great on a 10mb string

Comment: If you need to get the Plugin Manager first go: https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases

Comment: This still works even in Notepad++ v7.5.8. I just paste the downloaded `JSMinNPP.dll` file in the plugins folder of Notepad++. No need to create a folder to contain `JSMinNPP.dll`.

Comment: Notepad++ 7.6 was released a couple weeks ago and introduced the built-in Plugins Admin, making it super easy to install JSTool: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.6-released.html

Comment: This plugin is no longer compatible with v.7.5.9 and is automatically disabled.

Comment: The plugin still works for me as of Notepad v7.6.1. Try putting the DLL in its own plugin directory (i.e. `plugins/JSMinNPP/JSMinNPP.dll`)

Comment: It will also minify, which is a nice feature.

Comment: @Prakash I guess you mean when you use it on a JSON that has an extension it doesn'trecognize as JSON, such as .txt or .mcmeta? Yeah, apparently it properly recognizes such files as JSON after you do anything JSTool with them. A neat and useful side effect.

Comment: If JSTOOL and JSONVIEWER are not working, make sure the file is NOT opened from inside a .zip file.  For some reason most plugins don't work correctly when the file is opened in windows from within a zip file.  Just extract the file first, then open in NP++ and plugins will work fin.

Comment: It's the middle of 2022 and JSTOOL still works as intended!  I was able to copy junky results of an API call to readable JSON.

Comment: Formatting isn't compatible with folding, unfortunately. Quite annoying.

Comment: https://paulsofts.com/how-to-re-format-json-in-notepad/

Comment: If you need to install the plugin MANUALLY: you need to create a subfolder with the same name as the .dll file. (JSMinNPP.dll must reside in /plugins/JSMinNPP/JSMinNPP.dll)

Comment: How to make it automatic, such that if a valid json is recognized on file load, it will format it?

Answer (score 285):

For Notepad++ v.7.6 and above **Plugins Admin...** is available.

1. Open Menu Plugins > Plugins Admin...
2. Search **JSON Viewer**
3. Check JSON Viewer in List
4. Click on **Install** Button
5. Restart Notepad++
6. Select JSON text
7. Go to Plugins > JSON Viewer > **Format JSON ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> )**

We can install any Notepad++ supported plugins using **Plugins Admin...**

Comment: This is a very simple technique. Thanks. I just want to add in order to format after installing the plugin one needs 1) **Select** JSON objects 2) Go to **plugins **  3)**JSON Viewer** accordion  4) Lastly, **Format JSON**.                                         
**OR**                                                                                                                                                 Just hit **Cntrl + Shift + Alt + M**

Comment: plugins > Plugins admin no longer works in the current version.

Comment: @Michael Tuchman, May i know in which version Plugins > Plugins Admin... not work?

Comment: I have test Plugins > Plugins Admin... by JSON Viewer in latest version Notepad++ v7.8 and its working properly

Comment: @Hardik Leuwa : 7.6.6 (64 bit)

Comment: @Michael Tuchman, I have tested Plugins Admin.. in Notepad ++ 7.6.6 (64 bit) by this same JSON sample asked in question. and its working properly.

Comment: It works for my Notepad++ 7.8. Just make sure that your proxy is in place so the download background job can finish it job (no warnings or whatsoever if fails. Let it restart by itself.

Comment: FYI, I did not have a menu option for Plugins Admin in v7.9.1 32-bit- at least as a non-admin user. I do have it on 7.9.5 64-bit and up, for both admins and not. (Installing plugins does however require admin rights, sadly.)

Comment: JSON Viewer cannot parse log structured output from Serilog, for example. JSTool worked without problems.

Answer (score 238):

You require a plugin to format JSON. To install the plugin do the following steps:

1. Open notepad++ -> ALT+P -> Plugin Manager -> Select JSON Viewer -> Click
   Install
2. Restart notepad++
3. Now you can use shortcut to format json as **CTRL + ALT +SHIFT + M**
   or ALT+P -> Plugin Manager -> JSON Viewer -> Format JSON

[image]

Comment: This format algorithm is not robust and fails often, the JSTool (see answer of ibr) is much more robust.

Comment: @Stefan I can confirm. JSTool was able to parse log structured output from Serilog (.NET Core 6).

Comment: Note: It is now called "Plugins Admin..." instead of "Plugins Manager"

Answer (score 62):

I personally use [JSON Viewer](http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/) since the Notepad++ plugin doesn't work any more.

> **EDIT - 24th May 2012**
>
> I advise that you download the JSMin plugin for Notepad as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5083037/31532). This works well for me in the latest version (v6.1.2 at time of writing).
>
> **EDIT - 7th November 2017**
>
> As per @danday74's comment below, JSMin is now [JSToolNpp](https://github.com/sunjw/jstoolnpp). Also, please be aware that the JSON Viewer tool is on Codeplex which will likely disappear in the near future.

Given the above, this answer is no longer relevant and **you should use [Dan H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5083037/31532) instead**. My answer is simply here for posterity.

Comment: It works when I do `Plugins -> JSMin -> JSMin (New File)`  and then `JSFormat`

Comment: @danday74 Thanks! I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: JSON Viewer works fine on np++ version 7.5.1, available in the plugin manager.

Comment: @DanAtkinson Thanks for keeping your answer updated. I appreciate knowing that answers to old questions haven't gotten stale.  :)

Comment: still working on NotePad++ v7.8.2 Json viewer v1.34.0.0

Answer (score 43):

[Universal Indent GUI](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Plugin_Central) plugin for Notepad++ will turn your sample into:

```
{
    "menu" : {
        "id" : "file", "value" : "File", "popup" : {
            "menuitem" : [ {
                "value" : "New", "onclick" : "CreateNewDoc()";
            }
            , {
                "value" : "Open", "onclick" : "OpenDoc()";
            }
            , {
                "value" : "Close", "onclick" : "CloseDoc()";
            }
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work with the newest Unicode version of Notepad++ 5.5

Answer (score 37):

As per the latest `notepad++`, updated answer. Add `JSON Viewer` `Plugin`

Open `notepad++` go to `Plugins` --> click `Plugins Admin..`

[image]

In `Plugins Admin` window search for `JSON Viewer` and click on Install

[image]

New after installing plugin, this is how you can view file in JSON format

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Steps to add JSON viewer plugin for notepad++:

1. Download JSON viewer plugin for notepad++ from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/).
2. Copy **NPPJSONViewer.dll** into **Notepad++\plugins\NPPJSONViewer** folder
3. restart the notepad++
4. select JSON and click on plugins > JSON  Viewer > Format JSON (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+M).
5. Done.

Comment: Notepad++ says that plugin is not compatible with 64bit version of notepad , do we have any 64bit plugin ?

Comment: You could download it from https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer/releases

Answer (score 9):

simply go to this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/)
download the dll
copy and paste the dll to the plugins folder at notepad++, `\Notepad++\plugins`
restart the notepad++, and it should be shown in the list

[image: jsformatter]

NOTE: this dll supports 64 bit notepade++

Answer (score 7):

If formatting JSON is the main goal and you have VisualStudio then it is simple and easy.

1. Open Visual Studio
2. File -> New -> File
3. Select Web in left side panel
4. Select JSON
5. Copy paste your raw JSON value
6. Press Ctrl + K and Ctrl + D

That's it. you will get formatted JSON Value.

Comment: The question is about Notepad++

Comment: I was searching tool for format JSON values and found this link. Later I found Visual studio steps. It may useful for someone who is looking for formatting JSON values.

Comment: I usually resort to using this since my developer environment is reset from contract to contact. I just paste it into any .json, select all, copy, then undo.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an NPP solution, but in a pinch, you can use this online [JSON Formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) and then just paste the formatted text into NPP and then select Javascript as the language.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Thanks for that little nugget of advice! The JS highlighting has a weird gray background, python highlighting is much easier on the eyes.

Comment: Online json formatters are good but sometimes you don't want to risk sending the data you're formatting across the Internet.

Answer (score 5):

JSMinNpp plugin will do this job.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/

Answer (score 4):

The following Notepad++ plugin worked for me as suggested by "SUN"
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/

Answer (score 4):

You can view in Notepad++ no problem now (maybe older versions were bugged?)

for win64:
You can find the latest plugin here: https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer/releases . The latest zip file contains a .dll file.

And then follow the github priject README instructions:

> 1. Paste the file "NPPJSONViewer.dll" to Notepad++ plugin folder
> 2. open a document containing a JSON string
> 3. Select JSON fragment and navigate to plugins/JSON Viewer/show JSON Viewer or press "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J"
> 4. Voila!! if the JSON is valid, it will be shown in a Treeview

It should be the same process for win32 but I cannot personally verify it.

Answer (score 4):

you can use Notepad++ to format Json using Plugin **Admin** and **JSTool** but for those who can't install this plugin they can use Postman to Beautify json like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to install a Notepad++ plugin but you have Firefox and a JSON plugin for Firefox, you can select `Run -> Launch in Firefox`. You get the contents formatted as JSON using your Firefox plugin.

This is what I personally do.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me in the latest edition to Notepad using the UniversalIndentGui.

What I did was under the plugin setting choose Enable Text Auto Update, a window popped up and I selected javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Notepad 5.8.7 and jsmin 1.7.0.0 works wonderful here.

Be careful though, found out jsmin eats the comments the hard way (should have read first).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the JSON Viewer plug-in with NPP 5.9 and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but I recently ran into a problem with JSToolNPP not being compatible with my newly updated N++, I did find a replacement that seems to work.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/

Use at your own risk, ofc.  (standard disclaimer from me when linking anything outside the SExchange, fyi)

Answer (score 2):

For those of us behind a corporate firewall with no direct access to the internet, using the Plugins Admin won't work.  To use the JSMinNpp plugin, you can't just "copy the dll to the plugins folder".  It needs to live inside a folder called "JSMinNpp" inside the plugins folder. After doing that and restarting Notepad++, I was able to see the "JSTool" menu option under the Plugins menu.

Tested with Notepad++ 7.8.2 and 7.8.9.

Answer (score 2):

I use 32-bit Notepad++ version 7.5.6. I have found that 32-bit JSToolNpp 1.20.0
does a great job.
The direct link is:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/files/Uni/JSToolNPP.1.2006.0.uni.32.zip/download
which is redirected from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/.
VirusTotal link:
https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/008ee0ce889dfd9e96b975cebe6faafe28bc350352e951f3dec97e8e5bec5a07

[JSON-Viewer](https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer/releases/download/v1.40/NPPJSONViewer_Win32.zip)
works fine too, but cannot sort the JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.jsonlint.com/ to edit your `json` online if you don't have Notepad++.

Comment: Directly from N++? (-1)

Comment: upvoted. this link was usefull after the plugin wasnt accepted due to its 32bit version.

Comment: Upvoted. Provides a correct solution even though not through notepad.

Comment: For 32-bit version, I suggest taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65762242.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the Plugins Admin option, so the easiest way was to reinstall Notepad++ first (I was using v8.5.8) and select:

- Plugins
- Plugins Admin

(Also I simply reinstalled Notepad++ over the top of the previous install, I didn't uninstall first).

In Notepad++ I then went to Plugins → Plugins Admin and searched for the plugins I wanted:

- JSON Tools
- XML Tools
  (press Next if when you search "XML" the first one that comes up is "Npp Xml Treeview" instead).

I ticked them both then clicked Install.

Answer (score -10):

Your best bet is to use one of the latest versions of Eclipse (I am using Eclipse Galileo J2EE and Eclipse Ganymede J2EE). Create a JavaScript file, then create a variable:

```
var jsonObject = {"menu": {"id": "file","value": "File","popup": {"menuitem": [{"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},{"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},{"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}]}}};
```

Lastly, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and voila! You have a nicely indented JSON Object. I, too, am looking for a Notepad++ JSON formatter, and I very well may be forced to develop an Npp plugin some short time in the future.

Comment: If you have Visual Studio, simply paste the json text into a new file and it will be formatted automatically.

Comment: *I, too, am looking for a Notepad++ JSON formatter,* If you have same question please don't add an answer like this and keep SO clean ;).

Answer (score -11):

I know you asked about NotePad++ but TextMate for OS X can do it via the JSON bundle, its called the "Reformat Document" command.