# How to convert multiple repeating rows to columns and then from columns back to rows in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have multiple (+/- 2500) repeating rows in one column that I need to convert to a fixed set of columns which matches the repetition of the rows i.e. ABCDE-ABCDE, do my editing in column mode, then convert back to rows. This is an abridged example of my data:

```
A
B
C
D
E
A
B
C
D
E
```

I would like it to be like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E
A   B   C   D   E
```

Then convert back to rows.

Comment: Follow this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad

Comment: what you need is a json formatter plugin. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad) is a similar question

Comment: Well, JSMin will reformat the whole string above to `[{"E":{"T","H","U","L","D","N"},"S"},{"E":{"T","H","U","L","D","N"},"S"},]` (all on one line).

Comment: The data has been modified to show only simple text.

Comment: I know this can easily be done in Excel but would like to know if it is possible to do it in Notepad++ and I'm not familiar with using json.

Comment: After your edit, it is much easier: `^(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)` -> `$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. I am fairly new to all of this and I take it that this is to be put in the Replace field but I don't know what to put in the Search field.

Comment: *Find what*: `^(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)`.

Comment: *Replace with*: `$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5`

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor.  It did work just fine.

Comment: It converted the single column into five columns.  Now I just need to convert the five columns back into a single column.

Comment: Good, I posted an answer, please consider accepting it since it worked for you. Making the reverse is already another question, please post it with the input string, required output, the pattern you tried and brief description why it does not work.

Comment: Solved.  Thank you Wiktor.  I will post a different question on how to reverse the process.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, the answer is easy: you need to capture 5 subsequent lines and replace linebreaks between them with a tab character.

*Find what*: `^(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)\R+(.+)`
*Replace with*: `$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5`

Where `^` matches the line start, `(.+)` matches *and captures into a Group* a non-empty line (replace `+` with `*` if empty lines are to be considered), `\R+` matches 1 or more line breaks (be it a CRLF, CR or LF sequences).

In the replacement pattern, `$n` are backreferences to the corresponding group captured value.

[image]

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please consider accepting the answer.