# How to format JSON in notepad++

Tags: json, notepad++

I want to format JSON String in notepad++. Kindly guide me how to do so. I looked into this solution [Notepad ++ JSON Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad). It tells me to download the a tool from [This web site](http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/download.php). But I don't know which link to click out of 4 mentioned in that web site. Also, I just randomly downloaded one of the zip file and then unzipped it and it shows one dll file. Now what to do with that dll. Can some one guide me as I am a complete beginner. I have windows 10 running on my PC

**EDIT 1**
Some people are in so much hurry to give negative points. May be some people want to see code snippet even for this question. Huh!

**EDIT 2**
Anyways I tried below and IT DID NOT WORK

[image]

This is how my notepad ++ looks like **after installing them**.

[image]

**EDIT 3** 
Ok I fixed the issue. The problem is if you select multiple plugins together 
(multiple checkboxes) and install them there seems to be some issue with notepad++, so the solution for me was to install the plugin individually.

Comment: Plugins > Plugin Manager > JSON Viewer

Comment: Select `JSTool` and then install it.

Comment: Already did that. I still do not see any options under the Plugin dropdown. the screenshot attached is after instaling the plugin.

Comment: I didn't had `JSTool` so I installed it from your link and have screenshots about how to use the plugin dll, hope it helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reformat JSON in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad)

Comment: My choice is https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer. Works flawlessly with 20MB JSON.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to use the plugin manager of Notepad++ and search for the JSON plugin. There you can easily install it.

This answer explains it pretty good: [How to reformat JSON in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560464/how-to-reformat-json-in-notepad)

Comment: Can you kindly see my `EDIT 2`

Comment: On their website http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/screenshots.php it's listen as `JSMin`. Just go with `JSTool`. That should be fine. Select the checkbox and then install it.

Comment: Like I said I already did that. the screen shot is after installing those.

Comment: Even after installing them I do not see any option related to JSON in the plugins dropdown of notepad++

Comment: Did you restart your notepad++?

Comment: Yes it did that automatically. It had asked for a pop up. I selected YES to that.

Comment: Are you sure the installation succeeded? Do you have admin right on your pc?

Comment: Ok its working now. I selected all three checkbox and tried to install all of them. Turns our some sort of bug. One cannot install multiple plugins together. I checked just one plug in this time and installed it separately and now its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150014/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-kiril).

Answer (score 23):

Try with  [JSToolNpp](http://www.sunjw.us/jsminnpp/download.php) and follow the snap like this  then **Plugins | JSTool | JSFormat.**

[image]

Comment: Sucky part of this solution is that "JSFormat" also changes the language to JavaScript which comes with an ugly white font syntax format. It'd be nice if there was a way to tell "JSFormat" to change the language to JSON.

Comment: ryvantage: first of all, you confuse .json doc with "javascript language". javaScript is not a language by the way. You can switch between one-line minified json and format-json by going between JSTool->JSMin and JSTool->JSFormat.  If you don't like whitespace, you can configure them with JSTool->Options.  JSTool is beautiful, not ugly(Sucky?) like you said.

Answer (score 18):

Here are the steps to install `JSToolNPP` plugin on your Notepad++.

1. Download 64bit version from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/) or the
   32bit version if you are on a 32-bit OS.

   ```
   64bit - JSToolNPP.1.21.0.uni.64.zip: Download from SourceForget.net
   ```
2. Notepad++ before installation

[image: does not show JSTool in the Plugins menu.]

3. Unzip the downloaded `JSToolNPP.1.21.0.uni.64` and copy the `JSMinNPP.dll` and place it under `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins`.
4. Close Notepad++ and reopen it. If you have downloaded an incompatible dll, then it will complain, else it will open successfully. If it complains about incompatibility, go back to STEP 1 and download the correct bit version as per your OS. Check Plugins in Notepad++.

[image: JSTool is now located in the Plugins menu.]

5. Paste a sample unformatted but valid JSON data in Notepad++.
6. Select all text in Notepad++ `(CTRL+A)`  and format using `Plugins -> JSTool -> JSFormat`.

[image]

**NOTE:** On side note, if you do not want to install any plugins like this, I would recommend using the following 2 best online formatters.

- https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/
- https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: I needed to create subdir and rename e.g. "/plugins/JSFormat/JSFormat.dll" (NPP 7.8.5). Unless the parent folder and DLL had the same name, the plugin was not found.

Answer (score 2):

Always google so you can locate the latest package for both NPP and NPP Plugins.

I googled **"notepad++ 64bit"**. Downloaded the free latest version at [Notepad++ (64-bit) - Free download and software](https://download.cnet.com/Notepad-64-bit/3000-2352_4-77388575.html).  Installed notepad++ by double-click on **npp.?.?.?.Installer.x64.exe**, installed the .exe to **default Windows 64bit path** which is, "**C:\Program Files**".

Then, I googled **"notepad++ 64 json viewer plug"**.  Knowing SourceForge.Net is a renowned download site, downloaded [JSToolNpp download@SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsminnpp/).  I unzipped and copied **JSMinNPP.dll** to notePad++ root dir.

I loaded my newly installed notepad++ 64bit.  I went to **Settings** and selected **[import plug-in]**. I pointed to the location of **JSMinNPP.dll** and clicked open.

I reloaded notepad++, went to **PlugIns** menu. To format one-line json string to multi-line json doc, I clicked **JSTool->JSFormat** or reverse multi-line json doc to one-line json string by **JSTool->JSMin** (json-Minified)!

[image: All items are in this picture.]

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to install the plugin individually. I installed all the three plugins shown in the screenshot together. And it created the issue. I had to install each plugin individually and then it worked fine. I am able to format the JSON string.

Comment: check my answer, it requires you to place your dll in correct folder and Voila you are done!!

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find JSTool. Please see below url to see how I installed Notepad++

[How to view Plugin Manager in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad/46302069)

I created JSMinNPP folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins and copied JSMinNPP to it.

[image]

[image]