# How to view Plugin Manager in Notepad++

Tags: plugins, notepad++, editor

I downloaded Notepad++ from https://notepad-plus-plus.org/repository/7.x/7.5.1/npp.7.5.1.Installer.x64.exe.

And I installed the same. Now I need to install few plugins, but in the menu option *Plugins* there are only *Converter* and *MIME tools* listed, but not Plugin Manager.

[image]

Edit: They have removed Plugin Manager with the version 7.5. Still it can be added by following @johnny 's instruction in the best solution.
P.S: The plugin manager is only supporting the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

As of Notepad++ version 7.5, plugin manager is no longer shipped with Notepad++

From the [Notepad++ release notes](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-7.5-released.html):

> You may notice that Plugin Manager plugin has been removed from the official distribution. The reason is Plugin Manager contains the advertising in its dialog. I hate Ads in applications, and I ensure you that there was no, and there will never be Ads in Notepad++.
>
> A built-in Plugin Manager is in progress, and I will do my best to ship it with Notepad++ ASAP.

If the above doesn't put you off, and you want to proceed and install the plugin manager anyway, it looks like there's a GitHub repository for [nppPluginManager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager) - though I haven't personally used it, so cannot comment on it's validity.

The [nppPluginManager installation instructions](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/blob/master/doc/index.html#install) state:

> To install the plugin manager, simply download (links below) the .zip, and place the PluginManager.dll file in the Notepad++ plugins directory, and the gpup.exe in the updater directory under your Notepad++ program directory. (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\updater")
>
> In fact, if you prefer, you can just add the PluginManager.dll to the plugins directory, then do a reinstall of Plugin Manager from the plugin itself, which will place the file in the right place! Of course, if you're already using an earlier version of the plugin manager, you'll be able to just update from the update tab (or when you get the notification that the update has happened).

The GitHub repository also contains the [latest release](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases).

Comment: Hi @jonny. Thank a lot for your answer. I tried placing the dll and gpup.exe in the said folders, but the plugin manager still not showing after restarting notepad++. I also tried Settings->import plugins. Guess I need to install older version then.

Comment: hey it works with 32-bit notepad++. I followed the same steps with 32 bit version. :)

Comment: It doesn't appear to work with 64 bit version though. To me, this is a show stopper. I'm going to check out other editors :/

Comment: same, does nothing on x64

Comment: Create a folder with name "PluginManager" (same as dll file name) under plugins folder and place the dll file inside the new folder . Restart  NP++ , It will work .

Comment: In case someone else comes across this page, v8 of 64 bit notepadd++ has the plugin manager included. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v8/

Answer (score 64):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Download Plugin Manager from [here](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases/download/v1.4.12/PluginManager_v1.4.12_x64.zip).

   - You can find the most updated version in the [release section](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases) in the Git repository:
2. Extract the contents of zip file under "C:\Program Files\Notepad++"
3. Restart Notepad++

That's it !!

Comment: Nope. When restarting, N++ complains that gpup.exe cannot be found.

Answer (score 18):

To install a plugin without Plugin Manager:

1. Download your plugin and extract contents in a folder. You will find a .dll file inside. Copy it.
2. Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins`and paste the .dll
3. Run Notepad++

Comment: This is helpful. If you're on 64 bit the same instructions work - just copy the .dll to C:\program Files\Notepad++\plugins and make sure you have the 64 bit .dll (which I did not initially...)

Answer (score 13):

1. You can download the latest [Plugin Manager](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases) version PluginManager_latest_version_x64.zip.
2. Unzip the file.
3. Copy

> PluginManager_latest_version_x64.zip\updater\gpup.exe

into

> path-to-installed-notepad\notepad++\updater\

4. Copy

> PluginManager_latest_version_x64.zip\plugins\PluginManager.dll

into

> path-to-installed-notepad\notepad++\plugins\

5. Start or restart Notepad++.
6. Enjoy!

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me when trying to install JSTool w/ the most recent 64bit NPP.

Comment: This one works. gpup is also needed, besides the dll.

Comment: for the 32bit version I also had to create a new folder in ...\plugins\ named "PluginsManager".  And then move the file PluginManager.dll into that new folder. Then restarted Notepad++ (as Administrator but I dont know if that is essential).

Answer (score 8):

The way to install plugins seems to have changed, the previous answers here did not work for me.

The current (checked with 7.8.1) way to install plugins is to install it in a **sub folder**:

> The plugin (in the DLL form) should be placed in the plugins subfolder of the Notepad++ Install Folder, under the subfolder with the same name of plugin binary name without file extension. For example, if the plugin you want to install named myAwesomePlugin.dll, you should install it with the following path: %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Notepad++\plugins\myAwesomePlugin\myAwesomePlugin.dll

from https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/plugins/

So `PluginManager.dll` goes into `PluginManager` sub folder.

Comment: On my system it was `%PROGRAMFILES%\Notepad++\plugins\myAwesomePlugin\myAwesomePlugin.dll` .

Answer (score 6):

Notepad v7.6 includes a Plugin Admin and from this you can install Plugin Manager(note1) but it doesn't work fine with npp v7.6(note2)

On the other hand Plugin Admin is only available on NPP "Setup version" and after following conditions

- on Custom installation, "Plugin Admin" checkbox is enabled
- on Choose Components "Don't use %APPDATA%" checkbox is disabled

Plugin Admin will place plugins at  C:\ProgramData\Notepad++\plugins

(note1)Installation from Plugin Admin is not complete and \updater\gpup.exe is missing
(note2) Plugin manager is not using new plugins path and folder structure; from version 7.6 npp Plugins will be stored in individual folders (having same name than file.dll)

If you want to use npp7.6 portable, you can copy updater folder from Setup version, copy plugins from Setup version, or copy Plugins from npp v<7.6 and place each one in a individual folder.

[image: ![Plugin Admin feature]
[image: Installation npp76]
[image: Install Plugin manager from Plugin Admin]

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of Notepad++ got a new built-in plugin manager which works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

My system was 32 bit. I removed and re-installed Notepad++. After that from below got PluginManager_v1.4.12_UNI.zip and extracted it.

https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases

I created a folder called PluginManager at C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\ and copied PluginManager.dll into it. I restarted my notepad++ and now I see Plugin Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A direct process to install / configure `Plugin Manager` :

1. Download the latest version of NotepadPlus Plugin Manager from the
   official [Github handle](https://github.com/bruderstein/nppPluginManager/releases).
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Copy the `pluginmanager.dll` file and paste in `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Plugins\PluginManager` directory.
4. Restart the Notepad++

**Note**: Create the
    `PluginManager` directory if it is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ v8.1.2 has it where it used to be

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way was to reinstall Notepad++ (I was using v8.5.8) and select:

- Plugins
- Plugins Admin

(Also I simply reinstalled Notepad++ over the top of the previous install, I didn't uninstall first).

In Notepad++ I then went to Plugins → Plugins Admin and searched for the plugins I wanted:

- JSON Tools
- XML Tools
  (press Next if when you search "XML" the first one that comes up is "Npp Xml Treeview" instead).

I ticked them both then clicked Install.

Answer (score -1):

I changed the plugin folder name. Restart Notepad ++
It works now, a

Answer (score -3):

It can be installed with one command for N++ installer version:

```
choco install notepadplusplus-nppPluginManager
```