# Notepad++ Compiling C++

Tags: c++, notepad++, mingw

I'm trying to compile a simple C++ hello world program on notepad++. However, I have the newest 64 bit version (v7.5.4) and apparently they got rid of the plugin manager and nppexec. Which is kinda needed to compile and execute programs, according to the tutorials.

How do I compile a C++ program on the latest Notepad++? I've added MinGW bin directory to environmental variables and all that.

System: Windows 10 , x64 based.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the 32-bit version.

Comment: Use the 32-bit version.

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46301700/how-to-view-plugin-manager-in-notepad

Comment: Wow. So is the 64 bit version completely useless for any normal programming?