# Jsonviewer not working in Notepad++ 7.7.1 version

Tags: notepad++

I installed JSONViewer plugin for Notepad++ from 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjsonviewer/

```
however, I am not getting an option under Notepad++-->Plugin
```

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?  Are you trying to install through Plugins Admin?  Also, I think JSTool works better, but that's an opinion.

Comment: could not be a firewall issue. Other folks in team can access it. I am trying to install from Plugins admin. Is there any other way?

Comment: I've had the issue when at work, where I was behind a firewall, so had to set up the proxy to get the download.  The other time I had an issue was when I had NPP installed on two different drives on my computer.

Comment: Issue resolved when connected from home network. Thanks

Comment: Firewalls are the scourge of software updates.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate question which you might find your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58171302/4170504