# VB.NET Is it possible to export JSON data to a file in JSON format?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am wanting to know if it is possible to pickup JSON text from a server using a GET request, and then output that data into a local file in JSON format.

The only thing I can seem to find is this call:

```
File.WriteAllText(AgentWorkingDirectory & "\json.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(return_message))`
```

Which only seems to give me a continous line of unformatted text.

So instead of this:

```
{
    "AlertingRules":[
        {  
            "RuleId":1,
            "Name":"Unprocessed Directory",
            "RuleConditions":[
                {  
                    "Name":"FileCount",
                    "FileName":"",
                    ...
```

I get this:

```
{"AlertingRules":[{"RuleId":1,"Name":"Unprocessed Directory","RuleConditions":[{"Name":"FileCount","FileName":null,...
```

Comment: That compact format makes a lot of sense, as it saves disk space. You can still open the file with any editor that understands JSON and it will show it pretty-printed.

Comment: Okay, well when I open the file in a JSON editor it still remains unformatted.

Comment: @Riples If your content is already in JSON format and known to be well-formed, why not just write it to disk directly as you received it?

Comment: @Riples This answer about reformatting the JSON from notepad++ may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5083037/6638533...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the the formating parameter to your serialze call

```
File.WriteAllText(AgentWorkingDirectory & "\json.txt",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(return_message, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented))
```

See [Json.NET Documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_1.htm)

Comment: Oh wow.....can't actually believe I missed this.  Thanks so much, perfect answer.